# Removed character not highlighted in side-by-side markdown view

Tags: bug, revision-history

In the [6th revision of one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10503561/revisions), one of two headings that was changed from level 2 to level 1 does not have the second `#` highlighted as being removed (no red background).

## First heading change

Note that the second `#` *is* highlighted as being removed.

[image: Screenshot of first downgraded heading being highlighted]

[image: Screenshot of new version of first downgraded heading]

## Second heading change

Note that the second `#` is *not* highlighted as being removed.

[image: Screenshot of second downgraded heading *not* being highlighted]

[image: Screenshot of new version of second downgraded heading]